# How do you disable the back button on a lenovo T60?

Tags: laptop, button-remapping

There is an awful stupid key on the keyboard of this Lenovo T60 I'm using which sends the browser back a page.

I really need to disable it.

I can't find it anywhere in the Keyboard settings in control panel or the special Lenovo setup utility ("Thinkpad configuration").  Thinkpad Config has everything but keyboard.  Its got mouse, trackpoint..

Comment: I am feeling the same pain. I would, however, prefer to get *some* use out of the keys -- page up/page down, perhaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this information [here at Lenovo's support forums](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/How-to-disable-the-BACK-key/m-p/47960#M16288):

> **Disabling the "Browser Back Key":**
>
> Get the ThinkVantage Keyboard
> Customizer:
>
> http://support.lenovo.com/de/de/downloads/ds000695
>
> Install it:
>
> Note, after downloading/running the exe it
> does not install the app yet, it just
> extracts it. After the app gets
> extracted, go to the folder where you
> have it and run the setup. Then,
> reboot your laptop.
>
> Disable the Browser Back Key:
>
> Go to your Start menu,
>
> ThinkVantage,
>
> Keyboard Customizer Utility,
>
> Key sensitivity tab,
>
> uncheck Enable Browser Keys

Comment: @techie007 Except that this solution involves an extra process running in the background, rather than a one-off fix.

Comment: Welcome to the world of notebooks with specialty keys. :)  If removing _all_ the Lenovo bloatware doesn't disable them, then they've probably assigned those keys at the BIOS level (or alike).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the mouse trackpad supports multi-touch, and that when typing occasionally your hand/palm accidentally "swipes" across the trackpad, activating the "back" gesture. You should be able to customise or disable this in the trackpad configuration.

Edit: A solution for turning keys "off" is described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/), using [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html). [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would also work, but the SharpKeys solution changes the Windows registry, and so doesn't need to run in the background.

Comment: No its not that.  There's this really annoying "Back" button, it has a picture of a page with an arrow going back on it.  Its right next to the normal "left" arrow key.

Comment: @bobobobo Ah, I assumed it was the same problem I had with a laptop recently.

Comment: +1 for the SharpKeys suggestion. The back/forward buttons on my ThinkPads are remapped to page up/down using this tool.